# Is offline secure two party computation possible?

Tags: security, encryption

[image: Offline secure two-party computation]

Is there a solution for the following problem?

- We have a function f(x,y) where the inputs are secret an cannot be
  known by anyone besides the party that submitted them.
- The output of f is public and can be known by anyone.
- An adversary has access to any machine in the middle (not the devices of the two submitting parties).
- The computation has has to happen on a third party device without interacting with any of the owners of x and y more than once to get an input eg. Enc(x).

To me this sounds pretty much impossible, but since I cannot come up with a proof and the first time I heard of MPC all of it sounded impossible, let's give it a try.

Comment: The central problem is that the decryption `Dec(f(Enc(x), Enc(y)))` shall be possible, but `Dec(Enc(x))` and `Dec(Enc((y))` shall be impossible by the third party. This indicates f() needs some way to re-encrypt the output so that it can be decrypted with a different key, without being able to re-encrypt the inputs. This might indeed be possible for some functions f().

Comment: I find your description very hard to understand. Can you maybe try it differently?

Comment: You might also want to consider asking at https://security.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Hmm can you tell me specifically what you find hard to understand? I'm might ask there although I think a question about crypto design belongs here more then on the security stackexchange.

Comment: @amon so you say this would only be possible for a few functions f(). Would you know one concrete f() that definitely breaks it?

Comment: @Jakob Homomorphic encryption seems like it would be a good place to start. But if the output of f is public, the security of x and y are also going to depend a lot on the security properties of f.

Comment: @Jakob One obvious trivial f that is an issue is `f(x, y) = x` there is no way that the attacker is not going to know x if it is public.

Comment: For starters, I don't understand what your goal is. To find a suitable function `f`? What should this function do, besides compute something that may be publicly known? Where does `Enc` come in? An understandable explanation would be "I want to compute some function `f` on an untrusted device, without revealing the inputs `x` and `y` to the computation." Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your example exactly but I think you are talking about [homomorphic encrpytion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption):

> a form of encryption that permits users to perform computations on its encrypted data without first decrypting it.

It's a pretty nascent field and very inefficient compared to standard calcuations.

Answer (score 0):

One way hashes make it possible for f() = x == y,  x contains y etc  (although now the owner of x knows y and vice-versa, does this count?)

Technically functions which discard information like abs(x) + abs(y) can also work, as you can send x or -x and get the same result, the attacker would have have to make 4 guesses. But I'm not sure how secure this would be considered?

A generic solution for any f is impossible as shown by f() = x

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for some f, impossible for other f.

An example f for which it is possible would be bitwise xor:

Let f(x,y) := xor(x,y)
And enc(x) := xor(x,s) with s being a secret.
dec(x) would be the same as enc(x).

f(enc(x), enc(y)) = xor(xor(x,s), xor(y,s)) = xor(xor(xor(x,y),s),s) = xor(x,y)

An example for which it would be possible:
Let f(x,y) := (x,y)
This is trivial, because you cannot know (x,y) without knowing x and y